# Create User in AspNetUsers using WPF Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I'm creating a WPF application which accesses a database also used by a MVC5 based website.

On the MVC5 I know that creating a user we just need to

```
 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Now I need to do something similar on the WPF, but I've noticed that I don't access to the Usings to get the UserManager.
I know that on older versions of MVC using Membership we could just use the line

```
Membership.CreateUser(_userName, _password, _email);
```

But this isn't valid anymore for Identity 2.0 right?

After a bit of searching the web the only answer that I've found to solve my problem is something along the lines of

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56851/");
(...)
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/student/", student); 
(...)
```

But that doesn't seem very "dynamic" - is this the only way? Or I'm missing something.